# How to display alert after click on select option javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have searched around and tried various things but I cannot find a way to get javascript to alert my chosen option.

Why does not display an `alert` after `select option`?

```js
const selects = document.querySelectorAll('.group-select');
selects.forEach((elem) => {
  elem.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    alert(selects.length);
  });
});
```

```html
<select class="group-select form-control selectpicker" title="چیزی انتخاب نشده است" id="o1" name="o1">
  <option value="در استان محل سکونت" data-value="state">در استان محل سکونت</option>
  <option value="به صورت منطقه ای / ملی" data-value="region">به صورت منطقه ای / ملی</option>
  <option value="در مرکز تربیت مربی" data-value="teacher">در مرکز تربیت مربی</option>
</select>

<select class="group-select form-control selectpicker" title="چیزی انتخاب نشده است" id="o2" name="o2">
  <option value="در استان محل سکونت" data-value="state">در استان محل سکونت</option>
  <option value="به صورت منطقه ای / ملی" data-value="region">به صورت منطقه ای / ملی</option>
  <option value="در مرکز تربیت مربی" data-value="teacher">در مرکز تربیت مربی</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me, honestly.

Comment: Your code works, what is the issue? Currently you are alerting the number of select elements found by your querySelectorAll, is that what you want?

Comment: I know, but it doesn't work for me at all.

Comment: Use alert(elem) in callback to check whether you achieve it

Comment: Yes, it shows me the `alert(elem)`

Comment: Then, is it solved already?

Comment: No, it is not solved already........

Answer (score 0):

```js
const selects = document.querySelectorAll('.group-select');
selects.forEach((elem) => {
  elem.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    alert(elem.length); //to display the length
    alert(elem.value);  //to display the selected value
  });
});
```

```html
<select class="group-select form-control selectpicker" title="چیزی انتخاب نشده است" id="o1" name="o1">
  <option value="در استان محل سکونت" data-value="state">در استان محل سکونت</option>
  <option value="به صورت منطقه ای / ملی" data-value="region">به صورت منطقه ای / ملی</option>
  <option value="در مرکز تربیت مربی" data-value="teacher">در مرکز تربیت مربی</option>
</select>

<select class="group-select form-control selectpicker" title="چیزی انتخاب نشده است" id="o2" name="o2">
  <option value="در استان محل سکونت" data-value="state">در استان محل سکونت</option>
  <option value="به صورت منطقه ای / ملی" data-value="region">به صورت منطقه ای / ملی</option>
  <option value="در مرکز تربیت مربی" data-value="teacher">در مرکز تربیت مربی</option>
</select>
```

you are iterating the variable "elem" and when you are displaying alert you are using "selects".

Comment: you can run this snippet  in stackoverflow itself and you can see its running just fine. you must have error someplace else in your code.

Comment: try to add a alert without the loop. see if that works.

Comment: Yes, it works When I put this `selects.forEach((elem) => { alert(elem.id);`

Comment: But if I put it after `elem.addEventListener ('change', (event) => {alert (elem.id);` it will not work

Comment: you can try it with "click" event and also instead of using `elem.addEventListener ('change', (event) => {alert (elem.id);` you can use `elem.addEventListener('change', function() {
    alert(elem.value);
  });`

Comment: I got to replace this code, but my problem did not solve yet.........